# Ternary operator c# shorthand

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I have class Segment which has four instances of class `PricingDetailPer`  `PricingDetailPerAdult`, `PricingDetailPerChild`, `PricingDetailPerSenior`, `PricingDetailPerInfant`, and they all have property `Availability`.

In code i need to get property `Availability` but i need to check if Parent is exist. Is there shorthand like this:

```
return segment.PricingDetailPerAdult != null ? (this.Availability) : (continue checking);
```

where `this` refers to `segment.PricingDetailPerAdult` or some other property that i checking?

Comment: `this` refers to the class/struct instance you're executing the code in, as it always does. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this). `this` has nothing to do with the ternary operator syntax.

Comment: Please, Maybe I didn't express myself well. That doesn't need to be this, i just assking if there is some shorthand that shortens the code?

Comment: What does "check if Parent is exist" mean? You don't mention a parent anywhere else in your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity `PricingDetailPerAdult` is the parent for the `Availability`. So are the other three.

Comment: @GSerg - What does that mean? "is the parent for"? I understand that they are properties of the `Segment` class, but how they represent a "Parent" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity A "parent" of *something*, in the OP terms, is an instance that has *something* as its property and thus is one dot to the left from it in the accessor expression. For `segment.PricingDetailPerAdult.Availability`, the "parent" of `Availability` is `PricingDetailPerAdult` which may or may not be null. The "parent" of `PricingDetailPerAdult` is `segment`.

Comment: I know that "parent" is not right therm for the given context, but i thought it would be much more easier to understand what i wanted.

Comment: @AlmirHusić - Don't assume we'll know what you mean when you use an inexact term - try to explain in more detail what you mean. I found it confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return segment.PricingDetailPerAdult?.Availability
       ?? segment.PricingDetailPerChild?.Availability
       ?? segment.PricingDetailPerSenior?.Availability
       ?? segment.PricingDetailPerInfant?.Availability;
```

Reference:

[Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)
[?? operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)